# Change content when the user scroll down his screen on a android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm looking to change the layout of my app when the user scroll down.

I'd like something like this when the user is on the top of the screen.

[image]

and when the user scroll down, I'd like to make disappear progressively the top and replace it by a sort of static version.

[image]

Is it possible ? Any clue ? (I need it only on phone device)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with sticky headers for scrollview/listview/gridview. If I understand correctly, when the user scrolls down, the sticky header part (static N 3 stuff) should appear.

If so, check out Roman Nurik's [ScrollTricks](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/scrolltricks). Demo is on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PL9s0IJ9oiI).

Comment: hello tks for your answer. There are 3 parts. The first appears only on top and disappear after. The second appears when the first disappear (but not visible at the beginning). And the thirst. In this exemple I think that the static part is always visible.